# pointers to structs versus malloc in C?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct telephone
{
    char *name;
    int number;
} TELEPHONE;

int main()
{
    //TELEPHONE index;
    TELEPHONE *ptr_myindex;
    ptr_myindex = (TELEPHONE*)malloc(sizeof(TELEPHONE)); 
    //ptr_myindex = &index;

    ptr_myindex->name = "Jane Doe";
    ptr_myindex->number = 12345;
    printf("Name: %s\n", ptr_myindex->name);
    printf("Telephone number: %d\n", ptr_myindex->number);

    free(ptr_myindex);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this, it outputs the same result as when I don't dynamically allocate the pointer to the struct, and instead use the part in my code that has been commented out. Why does this happen?

Comment: Why would you think the storage duration of your structure object affects the behavior of your function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Why does this happen". Are you asking why it's possible to have pointers to stack allocated values? If so, why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: Is this homework? methinks it is.

Comment: @EdHeal The homework tag is in the process of being blacklisted. Please don't add it to new questions. Also this would be a pretty horrible homework question...

Comment: This wasn't homework. This is just me trying to have a better understanding of C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare:

`TELEPHONE index`

The compiler knows what kind of struct `TELEPHONE` is and so it allocates the memory needed by that struct.

For example:

```
int a = 5;
int *p = &a;
```

It's perfect. But if we want to achieve the same without `int a = 5`, we should do the following:

```
int *p;
p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*p = 5;
```

There's a difference tough. The first code allocate the variable in the `stack`, while the second code allocate it in the `heap`. But in the second case, there's no allocated space for the struct before the `malloc`, and the only allocated space is for the pointer itself (that do not need the same space as the struct itself).

Answer (score 2):

Your two versions of code do the following:

1. Allocate the struct on the heap.
2. Allocate the struct as a local variable.

These options are interchangeable in this program. The code that assigns to the struct, and then prints, doesn't care whether the struct was heap allocated or is a local variable.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you =)